# Can I load a .gltf or .glb file from the external storage

Tags: load, arcore, gltf

I have an Android device and work with ARCore and would like to load a Gltf or Glb file from an SD card. On the website https://developers.google.com/ar/develop/java/sceneform/create-renderables only loading over the internet is shown.

I read that `parse.fromFile` could help, but that did not work for me yet.

```
private static final String GLTF_ASSET =
   "https://github.com/KhronosGroup/glTF-Sample-Models/raw/master/2.0/Duck/glTF/Duck.gltf";

 /* When you build a Renderable, Sceneform loads model and related resources
 * in the background while returning a CompletableFuture.
 * Call thenAccept(), handle(), or check isDone() before calling get().
 */
 ModelRenderable.builder()
    .setSource(this, RenderableSource.builder().setSource(
            this,
            Uri.parse(GLTF_ASSET),
            RenderableSource.SourceType.GLTF2)
            .setScale(0.5f)  // Scale the original model to 50%.
            .setRecenterMode(RenderableSource.RecenterMode.ROOT)
            .build())
    .setRegistryId(GLTF_ASSET)
    .build()
    .thenAccept(renderable -> duckRenderable = renderable)
    .exceptionally(
        throwable -> {
          Toast toast =
              Toast.makeText(this, "Unable to load renderable " +
              GLTF_ASSET, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
          toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
          toast.show();
          return null;
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can. I tried with `gltf` and it works fine. I've downloaded the file to the file directory and specified the file path as the source url.

```
val fileName = "myfile.gltf"
val filePath = "${filesDir.path}/${fileName}"

ModelRenderable.builder()
        .setSource(this, RenderableSource.builder().setSource(
                this,
                Uri.parse(filePath),
                RenderableSource.SourceType.GLTF2).build())
        .setRegistryId(filePath)
        .build()
        .thenAccept {
            renderable = it
        }
        .exceptionally {
            // Error happened
            return@exceptionally null
        }
```

**Note:** If you have a `bin` file, download that as well.

Comment: thank you for your answer. I have a question. I don't want to download both gltf file and bin file separately. Can I download single file and show my model?

Comment: @Andev If you have a single file for your model, a glb or self-contained gltf, then you can use a single file to load it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can but you need to download both .gltf and .bin to a location in external storage and then call .gltf from there when you set renderable for a node in the scene.